# Count the Occurrences of an Attribute?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, select

I have an XML column in a large table that looks like this, in TSQL how would i count the number of times an attribute (LCPID) occurs?

Thanks,

---

The code:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <PingAutoRequest xmlns="http://Reply.LeadMarketPlace.Services.Ping.ServiceContracts/2007/10/ServiceContracts">
      <AutomotiveLead>
        <LCPId>766</LCPId>
        <Zipcode>33544</Zipcode>
        <Make>Ford</Make>
        <Model>Escape</Model>
        <LeadType>New</LeadType>
        <Year>2013</Year>
        <Trim>FWD S</Trim>
        <ExteriorColor />
        <InteriorColor />
        <Transmission />
        <TradeIn>false</TradeIn>
        <LastFourPhoneDigits />
        <LastName />
      </AutomotiveLead>
    </PingAutoRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, as your XML doesn't contain any [*attributes*](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) (apart from the namespaces) I'm going to assume you mean you want to count the number of `<LCPId>` [*elements*](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp). If so, then you could do that like this...

```sql
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://Reply.LeadMarketPlace.Services.Ping.ServiceContracts/2007/10/ServiceContracts' as ns) 
SELECT XmlColumn.value('(count(//ns:LCPId))','int')
FROM YourTableName
```

Note, we need to handle the [XML namespace using the `WITH` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the semi-colon is not a mistake. Then we count the number of elements with an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expression `count(//ns:LCPId)`.

You can see it in action at SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/14447).